# Scrcpy and Zoom

Tags: sharing, zoom-meeting

I am using Zoom to teach in my class using my tablet as a whiteboard. Using another machine, I would mirror the tablet using scrcpy and then share it via Zoom. Using my personal laptop, I can still mirror the same tablet using scrcpy, but it does not appear among the sharing options in Zoom.
In both cases, I am using Ubuntu 20.04.
Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Just chiming in to say that I have the same problem. For some reason, scrcpy doesn't show up among the windows that I can share in Zoom.